# Puppeteer mock page request object

Tags: node.js, mocha.js, sinon, puppeteer, eventemitter

```
import { Page } from 'puppeteer/lib/Page';
export class MonitorRequestHelper {
   public static monitorRequests(page: Page, on = false) {
    if(on) {
      page.on('request', req => {
        if (['image', 'font', 'stylesheet'].includes(req.resourceType())) {
          // Abort requests for images, fonts & stylesheets to increase page load speed.

          req.abort();
        } else {
          req.continue();
        }
      });
    } else {
      return true;
    }
  }
}
```

I am trying to mock and spy the function to check if it got called at least once.
Also, it would be helpful if some explain me how to mock and spy event-emitter object. 
The source code is available on https://github.com/Mukesh23singh/puppeteer-unit-testing

Comment: Did this answer your question? I answered why your test code in the repo did not work in the Sinon issue you created.

Comment: Yes, It worked thanks

Answer (score 1):

If you want to test that your logic in `monitorRequests` works, you need to pass in a fake `Page` object with an event emitter interface that produces a fake request that you can test on.

Something like:

```
import {spy} from 'sinon';

// Arrange
const fakePage = { on(type, cb) { this[type] = cb; } }; // "event emitter"
const fakeRequest = { 
  abort: sinon.spy(),
  resourceType() { return 'image'; }
};
monitorRequests( fakePage, true );

// Act
// trigger fake request
fakePage['request'](fakeRequest);

// Assert
assert(fakeRequest.abort.called);
```